# Rounded corners for primefaces radion buttons

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

What is the correct usage to avoid corners problem in IE 8 when radio buttons are used?
E.g.

I have `<p:column  id="rad" selectionMode="single"  />` in my datatable

In IE 8 radio buttons are rendered as check boxes which is a in a square box. So in order to resolve this I have used

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('rad').corner();      
    });
</h:outputScript>
```

However this didn't solve the issue.

So what is the correct way to have rounded corners for radio buttons?

Thanks

Edit 1

```
<h:head>

<style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[


      .radio input 
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.label_radio 
{
    background: url("/radio_labels.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
}

.label_radio.r_on 
{
    background-position: 0 -18px;
}

.radio label 
{
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 1.9em;
}


   ]]>
</style>
</h:head>


<h:outputScript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("1");
    $('.rad label').addClass('label_radio');
if ($('.rad input').length) {
    $('.rad input').each(function () {
        $(this).next('label').removeClass('r_on');
    });
    $('.rad input:checked').each(function () {
        $(this).next('label').addClass('r_on');
    });
};

    });
</h:outputScript>
```

and radio button in datatable.

```
<p:column  id="rad" selectionMode="single"  />
```

Comment: Images are best solution so far to get rounded corners in IE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I am doing:

**CSS:**

```
.radio input 
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.label_radio 
{
    background: url("images/buttons/radio_labels.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
}

.label_radio.r_on 
{
    background-position: 0 -18px;
}

.radio label 
{
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 1.9em;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.address_type label').addClass('label_radio');
if ($('.address_type input').length) {
    $('.address_type input').each(function () {
        $(this).next('label').removeClass('r_on');
    });
    $('.address_type input:checked').each(function () {
        $(this).next('label').addClass('r_on');
    });
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="address_type clear width">
<span class="radio twelvepx">
<input id="rbDelAddr" type="radio" value="0" name="AddrType">
<label class="label_radio" for="rbDelAddr">Delivery Address</label>
</span>
<span class="radio twelvepx">
<input id="rbInvAddr" type="radio" value="-1" name="AddrType">
<label class="label_radio" for="rbInvAddr">Billing Address</label>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `address_type` can be replaced with `rad`? And where do I get `radio_labels.jpg`

Comment: You can replace `address_type` with anything you want, because it's only a class name. You can create `radio_labels.jpg` image by yourself or find on google images etc.

Comment: I did exactly like how you have mentioned, however I am still seeing radio buttons as square boxes. Any thing else do I need to modify?

Comment: Added `HTML` example to be more clear. Maybe you see square boxes if you still using this line `$('rad').corner();`?

Comment: I have included my modified code as Edit 1 by editing my question.

Comment: What's the `html` output for `<p:column  id="rad" selectionMode="single"  />`?

Comment: html output is `<th id="form:dataTable:rad" class="ui-state-default ui-selection-column" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span></span></div></th>`

Comment: I have tried replacing rad with ui-dt-c which is the generated div class name, still it doesn't render as rounded corner.

Comment: As you can see in my example I have `<input type="radio">` and `label` after it. Your `html` is just a table heading element without radio input, so I don't know how and what are you trying to round? Is it a table heading itself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22310/discussion-between-polppan-and-morpheus)